# Mail server for windows

Tags: windows, email, mail-server

I am supposed to setup an internal mail server for my compnay.

Currently I am testing [hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/) and [ArgoSoft Mail Server](http://www.argosoft.com/rootpages/MailServerNetFree/QuickStart.aspx)
Can any one tell me which their good/bad experience with above mail servers.

am I missing any other good mail server ?

Comment: Have you considered using Google Apps as an email solution? This way you have plenty of space and a familiar interface. There's a free plan that allows you to create up to 50 email accounts (at least that's what I remember).

Comment: What email clients are you using? How many users? How many computers? What versions of Windows?

Comment: @alex : We want to implement internal mail server which will be used only by the staff and will be disconnected from outer world ( In general )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [xmail](http://www.xmailserver.org/) as a production intranet email server on windows because it is very easy to configure and administer while being quite feature rich. [Mercury](http://www.pmail.com/) is a bit tougher to administer, but has more features.

Comment: @tbscmc : I liked the XMail and tools. But I am going to stick with hMailServer currently. just because of matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely take a look at [SmarterMail](http://www.smartertools.com/SmarterMail/Features) if I were you. I've had great success with it in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, pop support, imap support, easy to run?

[Mercury mail transport](http://www.pmail.com/overviews/ovw_mercury.htm) is what i ran for quite a while, before i managed to get a dedicated box to run linux on. I'd also note it plays well with quite a few AV solutions as well. Its also been around for ages, and has been fairly actively maintained the whole time as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Microsoft Exchange or a hosted Exchange option? While this is an expensive option, it provides a stable system which is compatible with a variety of Windows Mobile devices, iPhones and provides a great small business scheduling systems through Microsoft Outlook.